# Why are the Cauchy Riemann equations enough to prove the differentiability of a complex function ??

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been studying complex analysis for a while,and I studied the Cauchy Riemann equations(C.R.E for short),and I've seen that if the real and imaginary parts' derivatives exist and are continuous and satisfy the the C.R.E then the complex function is differentiable. But I can't see why.
I know that for deriving the C.R.E we need to consider $dz$ approaching zero from the vertical direction (namely $dz=i dy $) and from the horizontal direction ($dz=dx$) and say that for the function to be differentiable the two limits must be equal and by setting the imaginary and real parts to be equal we are left with the C.R.E, but how is that enough to know that the derivative exists for all possible directions for $dz$ to approach zero?I tried letting $dz$ approach zero through the line $y=x$ but couldn't really get to anything.

Comment: Possibly of use: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m300/cauchyRiemann.pdf . From here: "Theorem 2 says that it is necessary for $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ to obey the Cauchy–Riemann equations in order for $f(x + iy) = u(x + iy) + v(x + iy)$ to be differentiable. The following theorem says that, provided the first order partial derivatives of $u$ and $v$ are continuous, the converse is also true — if $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ obey the Cauchy–Riemann equations then $f(x + iy) = u(x + iy) + v(x + iy)$ is differentiable."

Comment: Whatever direction you chose can be expressed as a complex number $c$ (with the real and complex parts giving you the coordinates for a vector pointing to that direction). Multiplying that complex number by $\epsilon$ (non zero real) yields the same direction. Your function is harmonic so $\frac{f(z + \epsilon.c) - f(z)}{\epsilon.c}$ will converge to $f'(z)$ when epsilon goes to 0.

In your example you can take $c = 1 + i$